# How to create a generic method that populates and returns an existing or a new Collection?

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently developing a storage library which lets the user persist objects to external storage. I wanted to add support for lists and sets so I added functions like this:

```
public <E extends Persistable> List<E> readList(String fileName, List<E> defaultValue)
public <E extends Persistable> Set<E> readSet(String fileName, Set<E> defaultValue)
```

Now I thought that it would be nice to add support for every type of `Collection`. I thought about something like this:

```
public <C extends Collection<E>, E extends Persistable> C readCollection(String fileName, C defaultValue)
```

My problem is the following: If the user calls `readCollection(FILE, collection)` and passes a non null `collection` as second parameter, I can use it  to add the stored items to that `collection`. But if the user has stored items before and passes `null` as second parameter I have to create a new instance of the `collection`. Is that even possible in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a default `Collection` instance, you can pass a `Supplier<C>`:

```
public <C extends Collection<E>, E extends Persistable> C readCollection(String fileName, Supplier<C> supplier)
{
    C collection = supplier.get();
    ...
    return collection;
}
```

Now you can use the `Supplier<C>` to create an instance of the `Collection`.

You'll can call that method with:

```
readCollection(name, ArrayList::new)
```

or:

```
readCollection(name, HashSet::new)
```

If you still need the functionality of adding elements to an existing `Collection` instance, you can create two methods -  `readCollection` and `readNewCollection`.

As an alternative, you can keep your single `C readCollection(String fileName, C defaultValue)` method, and decide which instance to create when `null` is passed as the second argument. For example, you can decide the default type is `ArrayList`.

BTW, you would have the same problem even if you kept the original two methods - `readList` and `readSet` - since `readSet` can return any `Set` implementation, so if the second argument is `null`, it will have to decide which `Set` implementation to use.